# How to clear validation in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, validation

Greetings,
I use ASP.NET validation control and I want to reset them whenever the user click on a button "*Create new stuff button* as an example" and I don't want to set it to an empty error message.
How can this be done in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add

```
 CausesValidation="false"
```

as an attribute to any button that you do not want to validate the page.

Answer (score 1):

Use Validation groups. Very Important so that controls dont interfere with each other.
To set the Message, use the 'errormessage' attribute.

Here's an example of a proper Validation Control

```
<asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1"
  controltovalidate="NameTextBox"
  validationgroup="PersonalInfoGroup"
  errormessage="Enter your name."
  runat="Server">
</asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
```

Read more on this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx) article